# Kubernetes: load-balance across two different namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

I want to deploy different versions of the same application in production:

```
kubectl create deployment hello-server --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0 -n test-a
kubectl create deployment hello-server --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0 -n test-b
kubectl expose deployment hello-server --port 80 --target-port 8080 -n test-a
kubectl expose deployment hello-server --port 80 --target-port 8080 -n test-b
```

I've tried to load-balance it like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.org/server-snippets: |
        upstream test-servers-upstream {
          server hello-server.test-a:80;
          server hello-server.test-b:80;
        }
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test-servers.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: test-servers-upstream
              servicePort: 80
```

but it returns an error:

> /   test-servers-upstream:80 (<error: endpoints "test-servers-upstream" not found>)

Services:

```
$ kubectl get services -n test-b         
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
hello-server   ClusterIP   10.128.199.113   <none>        80/TCP    75m
$ kubectl get services -n test-a 
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
hello-server   ClusterIP   10.128.207.6   <none>        80/TCP    75m
```

How can I load-balance it?

Comment: Could you show the names of service objects?

Comment: @GiovanniPatruno, here are the service names, I can't format it properly

$ kubectl get services -n test-a -o wide
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
hello-server   ClusterIP   10.128.207.6   <none>        80/TCP    71m   app=hello-server
$ kubectl get services -n test-b -o wide
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
hello-server   ClusterIP   10.128.199.113   <none>        80/TCP    71m   app=hello-server

Comment: @GiovanniPatruno, I've updated the question with the service objects for better formating

Comment: I was looking at the API reference and it seems that only one service name could be specified. I understand your "trick" to add the nginx snippet to set an alias but I'm afraid that this can't work.
Have you tried to simply put `hello-server` as `ServiceName` ?

P.S. [This](https://v1-16.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#ingressbackend-v1beta1-networking-k8s-io) is the doc page I read.

Comment: @GiovanniPatruno good finding. Is there any other way to load-balance across multiple namespaces?

Comment: looking at the [ingress nginx doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/), the default behaviour is to watch all the namespaces, so for me it's already working like that.
Have you tried to just change the `ServiceName` to `hello-server`? @rodrigo-estebanez

Comment: @GiovanniPatruno, changing to simply `hello-server` throws this error: ` /   hello-service:80 (<error: endpoints "hello-service" not found>)`. The Ingress object lives in the default namespace. If i declare Ingress in the test-a namespace it will only find the service that lives in that namespace.

Comment: @GiovanniPatruno, I believe that https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/ refers to where the `Nginx  Ingress Controller` looks for `Ingress` objects not for Service objects

Comment: I don't understand where the `hello-service` in your error log comes from your setup
I'm referring to this: ` / hello-service:80 (<error: endpoints "hello-service" not found>)`.
@rodrigo-estebanez

Answer (score 4):

Fresh `ingress-nginx` supports weight-based canary deployments out of box.
Looks like what you're asking for.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary.

Great example here.
https://medium.com/@domi.stoehr/canary-deployments-on-kubernetes-without-service-mesh-425b7e4cc862

Basically, you create 2 identical ingresses, one for each namespace.
They are different only in annotations and in pointing to different services.

```
# ingress for a service A in namespace A
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  namespace: demo-prod
spec:
  rules:
  - host: canary.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: demo-prod
          servicePort: 80
        path: /

# ingress for a service B in namespace B
# note canary annotations
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: "20"
  name: demo-ingress
  namespace: demo-canary
spec:
  rules:
  - host: canary.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: demo-canary
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Note, that `ingress-nginx` canary implementation actually ***requires*** your services to be in different namespaces.